# Windows computer needs a restart every time it goes to sleep

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep

Every time my computer goes into sleep mode, nothing will wake it back up without a force restart. Moving the mouse and pressing keys on the keyboard makes the keyboard activate (the numlock indicator turns back on), but the computer doesn't load up to the lockscreen. Instead I just get the blank "no signal" screen on my monitor.

The only fix I have for this is to force shutdown the computer (by holding the power button) and turning it back on, but that's probably not good for the computer. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Update the BIOS and the Power Driver for your system. Restart, go to advanced power options and make sure they are set properly for your computer

Comment: Are you sure it’s in S3 mode and not S4 mode?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop computer on standby and   sleep mode then You can disable by changing

In windows advanced power dialogue box display hard disk  to sleep never or increasing hours

And 
Disable power option in bios

If you want sleep mode to be active

Try alt +tab or shit+tab or windows key on keybord to activate from sleep mode to deactivate

If not then go to advanced power dialogue box find hard disk and change it to never and apply

Then update bios by the downloading it from manufacture website

Update windows latest device packs

Update download install original chipset display drivers from motherboard manufacturer company website

Then change default or increase hours of advanced power options